# How to fix the disappearance of bootstrap template from my laravel project

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I downloaded a laravel project from a shared hosting and I want to edit him in my localhost but when I type out the home adress: localhost:8000/ it shows me those two errors :

> Warning: require_once(C:\Users\Rafaa\Downloads\Compressed.idea/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Rafaa\Downloads\Compressed.idea\server.php on line 21.
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Rafaa\Downloads\Compressed.idea/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Rafaa\Downloads\Compressed.idea\server.php on line 21.

then I found a solution which is to remove some code from the server.php

the line :

```php
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Become :

```php
require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';
```

then the error fixed and the website worked in my localhost but the design is gone , it show me a static html website without any color or image or any thing.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there are any errors relating to asset paths and things not being loaded in?

Comment: there's no error just the line of starting the localhost on port 8000

Comment: try to run `composer dump autoload`, `clear cache for all view route config` and see if that helps

Comment: @somsgod , didn't work !

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing any images or designs(CSS/JS) probably because your all assets and images are having `public` folder in url, check the console of browser and see what errors you get.

You will have to remove `public` for all the urls otherwise you won't be able to run project with `php artisan serve`

Comment: there are many errors , but it seems not a solution to delete public from all urls !!

Comment: You can use xampp in that case

Comment: Move index.php outside the public dir and make necessary adjustment to it

Comment: mate I want to download the project from the hosting and works without editing any thing the question is why it is worrks in hosting and in my local server no ? , I don't want to delete public folder or to edit index.php , I want to know the source of the error

Comment: Most of the time laravel project is executed from public dir, but shared hosting does not allow you to change dir path which is pointed to public_html, in order to make laravel project to work we can move index.php to the root of the project from public dir. 

When you run php artisan serve, it will execute from public folder so if you run your project with xamp or wamp it should work